# How to read customize props of multple childs in parent component in a ReactJS with Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to read a customize props (id) that I made in a multiple childs on parent component (ReactSpringCarousel), but I don't know how I need type the component to do that. Here is the problem:

If I explicity type the node childs like below it's work:

```
 <ReacSpringCarousel>
    <img id="1" src={guitar1} alt="violao1" height="auto" />
    <img id="2" src={guitar2} alt="violao2" height="auto" />
    <img id="3" src={guitar3} alt="violao3" height="auto" />
 </ReacSpringCarousel>
```

But when I convert this test to use the api result, using a map funcition like this:

```
 <ReacSpringCarousel>
  {announce._source.photos.map((photo) => (
    <img
      id={photo.unique_filename}
      src={photo.url}
      alt={photo.original_filename}
      height="auto"
    />;
  ))}
</ReacSpringCarousel>
```

I have an error on typescritp.

This is the way that I type the ReactSpringCarouse:

```
interface ChildrenProps extends JSX.Element {
  props: {
    id: string;
  };
}

interface CarouselProps {
  children: ChildrenProps[];
}

const Component: React.FC<CarouselProps> = ({ children }) => {
  const childrensItens: CorouselItens[] = [];

  children.map((item) => {
    childrensItens.push({
      id: item.props.id,
      renderItem: item,
    });
  });
```

This is the message error:
This JSX tag's 'children' prop expects type 'ChildrenProps[] | (ChildrenProps[] & string) | (ChildrenProps[] & number) | (ChildrenProps[] & false) | (ChildrenProps[] & true) | (ChildrenProps[] & ReactElement<...>) | (ChildrenProps[] & ReactNodeArray) | (ChildrenProps[] & ReactPortal)' which requires multiple children, but only a single child was provided.  TS2745

Why it's thinking that map functions return only one child?

I appreciate any help.

Thanks.

Comment: you want ReacSpringCarousel to allow only img components as its children?

Comment: try adding `key` property to the image

Comment: [I can't reproduce your error](https://tsplay.dev/w62x6w)

Comment: Yes, ReactSpringCarousel will receive the img as a child.

Comment: I try to change id by key, but still the same problem, how can i create a component to receive multiple childs and read in this parent component the props that I made in the child component, this is the question.